# zmq_socket() is giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, zeromq

I am learning zeromq and have the following test code:

```
void *context = (void *)zmq_ctx_new();

if (context == NULL) {
    printf("context is null\n");
} else {
    printf("context was created successfully\n");
}

printf("connecting to the 0mq server\n");
void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);

printf("got socket\n");

if (responder == NULL) {
   printf("responder is null\n");
} else {
   printf("responder was created successfully\n");
}
```

When I run the code, it crashes when the `zmq_socket()` is called. Here is the output:

> Starting 0mq server context was created successfully connecting to the
>   0mq server Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I'm not sure why `zmq_socket()` fails. I have tried to move the zmq library in the beginning of the linking series in my Makefile. It still fails.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: my first statement: void context = (void)zmq_ctx_new(); is actually, void *context = (void*)zmq_ctx_new(); Don't know why it did not take the * there. anyway.. just wanted to clarify it

Comment: Where does your debugger say the segfault is occuring?

Comment: Why the cast in the 1st statement? Is is not necessary in C to cast here. If the compiler complains without it you probably found the cause to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
void context = (void)zmq_ctx_new();
```

into

```
void *context = (void *)zmq_ctx_new();
```

And, as I tried your code, void context = (void) zmq_ctx_new() would cause compile error.

here is my code which can work on my OSX.

```
gcc -o cli client.c -lzmq
gcc -o srv server.c -lzmq
```

client.c:

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf ("Connecting to hello world server…\n");
    void *context = (void *)zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");

    int request_nbr;
    for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
        char buffer [10];
        char snd[] = "hello";
        printf ("Sending Hello %d…\n", request_nbr);
        zmq_send (requester, snd, sizeof(snd), 0);
        zmq_recv (requester, buffer, 10, 0);
        printf ("Received World %d\n", request_nbr);
    }
    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

server.c:

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{   
    //  Socket to talk to clients
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new (); 
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == 0); 

    while (1) {
        int  nrecv;
        char buffer [10];
        nrecv = zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0); 
        printf ("[%d] Received %s\n", nrecv, buffer);
        sleep (1);          //  Do some 'work'
        zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0); 
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. That is the way my code is. For some reason, my stars are not being displayed here.  my code is exactly the way you have suggested.

Comment: The weird part is that if I call zmq_socket(&context, ZMQ_REQ) then the segmentation fault does not happen, but the created socket is NULL. I know that passing an address to context is a wrong call though. But, it is telling me that the problem may not be the code. I don't know

Comment: @Kavita, zmq_socket(&context, ZMQ_REQ) is not correct, zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ) is correct. context is a pointer returned by zmq_ctx_new(), you cannot pass the address of the pointer into zmq_socket. Just pass the pointer itself into zmq_socket.

Comment: yes, I am using exactly the same code. but, the call to the zmq_socket fails and creates a core dump.

Comment: The issue is resolved. It was the library-related issue. Thanks for your helo